# Login to npm with multiple scopes

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm` allows to assign a scope to a registry at login like this:

```
npm login --scope=@my-company-name --registry=http://your-server-address:8080
```

Is it also possible to assign multiple scopes at a particular login?

Because docs say:

> Scopes have a many-to-one relationship with registries: one registry can host multiple scopes, but a scope only ever points to one registry.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to login multiple times using different scopes:

```
npm login --scope=@scope1 --registry=http://your-server-address:8080
npm login --scope=@scope2 --registry=http://your-server-address:8080
```

After this you can use packages scoped with `@scope1` and `@scope2`.